# How to listen to 2 ServiceBus queues with different MaxConcurrentCalls each?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I have made a WebJob program using `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions` and `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` that listens to an AzureServiceBus queue with a **MaxConcurrentCalls** of 3.

Host Configuration:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            startup.ConfigureServices(services, hostContext.Configuration);
        }).ConfigureWebJobs((hostContext, webJobsBuilder) =>
        {
            webJobsBuilder
                .AddAzureStorageBlobs()
                .AddServiceBus(options =>
                    {
                        options.AutoCompleteMessages = true;
                        options.MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                        options.MaxConcurrentCalls = 3;
                    }
                );
        });
```

Handler:

```
public async Task MyQueueHandle1([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue1")] string message)
{
    _log.Info("this queue was triggered!");
}
```

Now I added a second queue with the same connectionString but I want to set a **MaxConcurrentCalls** of 10 for this last queue. Since the documentation is not updated in Microsoft's docs and this library is a bit old, I don't know how to configure these 2 queues. Maybe I should use another lib? Or is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Trigger settings are defined in the `host.json` and are shared by all functions in the Functions application. If you need different settings for the second queue, you'll need to deploy it as a different Functions app.